# What are the advantages and disadvantages of dynamic linking SDL 1.2 vs static linking SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, static, sdl, sdl-2

What are real advantages and disadvantages - from game developer perspective, and future distribution of the game - what is "the best choice" ? My platform of choice is now Linux Mint 16 but will be expanded to other like Win7 and maybe Android.

Comment: Static linking will probably be unnoticeably faster and will result in just one file. Dynamic linking will be unnoticeably slower and result in multiple files, but if there are multiple programs that use the same dynamic library, you only need one instance in memory that will be shared across processes. In a game context, statically linking is probably better, but don't expect any significant result from either choice.

Comment: Also, your question title mentions two versions of SDL. Is that a mistake?

Comment: For distribution, you only need one executable and no DLLs (.so) if it is staticly linked.  Also, it doesn't depend on which version of OS the DLLs were built on.  eg you could run something built on Mint16 on Mint12.

Comment: @zneak it's not a mistake, AFAIK SDL 1.2 cannot be statically linked without breaking the library license as opposite to SDL 2.0